'Subroutine respecting' in the Universal Composability Framework?
I've been trying to understand the execution model in the UC framework.
Suppose Alice (A) wants to communicate to Bob (B) via a channel (Ch). I have a mental picture that looks like the following:
      |     |
     [A]   [B]
       \   /
        \ /
        [Ch]

In this picture, there is no adversary involved. The environment connects to the 'open' ports of A and B, to form a picture that looks a little bit like this:
       [Env]
        / \
       /   \ 
     [A]   [B]
       \   /
        \ /
        [Ch]

Informal semantics that I want

All the boxes (Env, A, B, Ch) are interactive turing machines
In this 'protocol', the machines A, B, and Ch simply forward messages from one end to another. To be more precise, each of these ITMs has two bidirectional channels each. When a message is input on one channel, it gets output on the other channel.


Can this be considered a valid system in the UC framework?
What confuses me is the notion of 'caller identity' and 'subroutine identity'. In this system, is Ch a subroutine identity of both A and B? Moreover, suppose, we send a message to A, which forwards it to Ch. Can Ch (being a subroutine identity of B) 'just send' a message to B without it having sent a message first?
Note: Here, I don't have an adversary. However, I think that we can consider that an adversary does exist, but there are no backdoor connections.

To answer your question, I think that some clarification is needed: You write say that Env, A, B and Ch are interactive Turing machines (ITMs). Did you mean ITM instances (ITIs) instead? To me it seems like Env, A, B and Ch are ITIs.
Secondly, there are multiple versions of Canetti's UC paper. Do you refer to the latest version on eprint?
Finally, please note that subroutine respect is defined with respect to sessions (and not individual ITIs). Can you provide the extended identities for each ITI? That is, specify the session identifiers for each ITI and which ITIs run the same code?

In the last question of my comment, it should of course say "session identifier" (singular) instead of "session identifiers" (plural). (Each ITI has only a single session identifier.)

@JuliusHardt I will admit that I'm not an expert at UC nuances. However, what I did have in mind was something like 2 WARMUP: A RESTRICTED MODEL in https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3402457. Perhaps, 'subroutine respecting' does not even make sense there?
